# Convergent Sequence from Introduction to Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, continued-fractions

> Consider the sequence of real numbers
>   $$\frac 12, \cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 1 2}, \cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 12}}, \ldots.$$
>
> Show that this sequence is convergent and find its limit by first showing that the two sequences of alternate terms are monotonic and finding their limits.

(From Introduction to Analysis by Maxwell Rosenlicht)

I am not sure if I have burned out or what, but I *cannot* do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So do we have

$$x_{n+1} = {1\over 2 + x_n}?$$

If so, I can edit this answer to produce a solution.
It appears so.

So, in the steady state, we have $x_n = x_{n+1}$. We solve this equation

$$t= {1\over (2 + t)}.$$

Multiplying, 
$$ t^2 + 2t = 1.$$
so
$$ t^2 + 2t -1 = 0.$$
Availing ourselves of the quadratic formula we get
$$ t = {-2\pm \sqrt{4 + 4}\over 2} = -1\pm \sqrt{2}.$$
In this case, you will be attracted to the positive root $\sqrt{2} - 1$.

Comment: I think your original, unedited answer was what the OP needed. Upvote retracted.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I needed. Lol.

Comment: Perhaps I don't quite understand where you're coming from. The above form makes sense, but I don't see how the entire condition of the problem would be satisfied with the rest of that.

Comment: -1 answer fails to show the sequence actually converges.